# Why in Android studio i can not find most of Attributes to add for views in XML layout like padding,textSize and etc

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Before when in XML layout I was typing {t} android studio brings some suggestion and by chose which one I want it completed  automatically
and still in the old project Suggestion and Auto Complete is working  like below image
[image: thisOneIsok]

But in new project when i want to add Vertical orientation at most it suggest orientation and i should write vertical completely by myself
and for  example to define "textSize"  i should write completely by my self and android doesn't suggest

[image: itHasProblem]

also for adding new View i should write most of things like below attributes completely by myself and i got headache !

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

my Android studio version is 3.6.1

Comment: Did you try try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: yes i tried and didn't work

Comment: thanks for your attention but i tried this before too and didn't work

Comment: you mean invalidate Cashes/Restart ? if yes i did it also before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211689/discussion-between-android-id-and-amir-hossein).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some  Days for looking answer and try so many suggestions (some comments for this question and answer 
(clear cache, delete cache,delete .gradle folder, do invalidate caches , or delete all .imp or .idea folder and restart android studio , try some new projects)
) unfortunately it couldn't solve my problem so I decide to re Install Android studio , so its obvious now it works( its the last way )

Answer (score 0):

if you get this error during your development time then 
please run following command to clear gradle cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/
```

after that please click on `Invalidate Caches/Restart` from File menu then further processing will happen which dowloads all the libraries again so it takes time but also resolves this issue.

Comment: You can see terminal at the bottom of Android Studio. Please click on it . It opens terminal window and then write this command

Comment: i wrote your command and get error"'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: If you are using Windows then please use rd -rf ~/.gradle/caches/ (just changed rm to rd)

Comment: Invalid switch - ".gradle".

Comment: For Windows :

gradlew cleanBuildCache
On Mac or Linux:
./gradlew cleanBuildCache please use these command as per your OS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211708/discussion-between-amir-hossein-and-jaimil-patel).