# I have upgraded JDK 8 to JDK14 and I got some problems in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, java-14

I have upgraded JDK 8  to JDK14 and I got some problems in android studio , and i want to return it back , any body can help me to completely downgrade to resolve  problems 
one problem that i asked in the below link,i think if i can return completely back it could work :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222586/why-in-android-studio-i-can-not-find-most-of-attributes-to-add-for-views-in-xml/61226681?noredirect=1#comment108315792_61226681)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a Windows Machine,

- **access the Control Panel**:

In Windows 7 select the Windows button, then select Control Panel.

In Windows 8, 8.1 right-click in the bottom left corner of the screen, then select Control Panel.

In Windows 10 click in the search box on the bottom left corner of task bar (either cortana or the magnifying glass) and type "Control Panel"  Click on the icon that appears.

- **Select Programs and Features**
- **In the list of programs, select the undesired version of Java, then click Uninstall. (If you have multiple versions of Java installed, you may want to uninstall all of them.)**

Uninstall the update you had installed and later restart your machine. Once it restarts, now go to Oracle's [Java SE 8 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) page and locate the desired version of Java. Enjoy!!